# Spring @Transactional method issue

Tags: java, database, hibernate, transactions, h2

So, I have a controller `[POST]` method which is basically supposed to create a `transaction`

Logic is simple, while creating `transaction` **two accounts** should be involved(this is scenario), into `transaction` I am passing 3 fields - `amount`, `emitterId` and `receptorId`. After the transaction is being created, the senderBalance should be **decreased** by `transaction.amount` and receiverBalance should be **increased** by `transaction.amount`, but for some reason nothing changes

Here's the code:

```
@Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TransactionRepository transactionRepository;

@Transactional
    @PostMapping("/transactions")
    public ResponseEntity<Transaction> createTransaction(@Valid @RequestBody Transaction transaction) {
        final Transaction result = transactionRepository.save(transaction);
        final URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().
                path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(result.getId()).toUri();
        Integer emitterBalance = accountRepository.findById(result.getSenderAccountId()).get().getBalance();
        Integer receptorBalance = accountRepository.findById(result.getReceiverAccountId()).get().getBalance();
        Integer amount = transactionRepository.findById(result.getId()).get().getAmount();
        Integer emitterFinalBalance = emitterBalance - amount;
        Integer receptorFinalBalance = receptorBalance + amount;
        accountRepository.findById(result.getSenderAccountId()).get().setBalance(emitterFinalBalance);
        accountRepository.findById(result.getReceiverAccountId()).get().setBalance(receptorFinalBalance);
        transactionRepository.save(result);
        transactionRepository.save(transaction);
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
```

***Entities***
Transaction

```
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Integer amount;
    private Instant created;
    private Long senderAccountId;
    private Long receiverAccountId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "emitterId")
    private Account emitterId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "receptorId")
    private Account receptorId;

    public Transaction(Integer amount, Account emitterId, Account receptorId){
        this.created = Instant.now();
        this.amount = amount;
        this.emitterId = emitterId;
        this.receptorId = receptorId;
        senderAccountId = this.emitterId.getId();
        receiverAccountId = this.receptorId.getId();
    }

}
```

Account

```
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String holder;

    @NotNull
    private Integer balance;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "emitterId",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Transaction> transactionsMade;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receptorId",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Transaction> transactionsReceived;

    public Account(String holder, Integer balance){
        this.holder = holder;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public Account(Long id){
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Could You help me to fix this issues, please :)?

Thank You in advnace!

Comment: Could you please also provide your transactionRepository declaration in your controller.

Comment: A moment, please, Ill update the code in 30sec

Comment: Where exactly do you change the value of `result` or `transaction` in your method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
    accountRepository.findById(result.getSenderAccountId()).get().setBalance(emitterFinalBalance);

accountRepository.findById(result.getReceiverAccountId()).get().setBalance(receptorFinalBalance);
```

replace with

```
Account sender = accountRepository.findById(result.getSenderAccountId()).get();
sender.setBalance(emitterFinalBalance);
accountRepository.save(sender);

Account receiver = accountRepository.findById(result.getReceiverAccountId()).get();
receiver.setBalance(receptorFinalBalance);
accountRepository.save(receiver);
```

Comment: Now it blames this line:

Integer emitterBalance = accountRepository.findById(result.getSenderAccountId()).get().getBalance();

with Exception : "The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!",

Comment: Could you place breakpoint and check that incoming parameter "transaction" has senderAccountId? I can't understand how the change that I proposed can lead to this error.

Comment: Nono, I just figured out that this is not caused by the changes that u proposed. That's something that was before. 
P.S. transaction has only "id" and "amount" but senderAccountId is nulled :/

Comment: P.S. It's okay I was passing emitterId and receptorId into post requestbody, now passing senderAcconutId and receiverAccountId and its fine

Comment: btw, if you could take a look on my anotehr question regarding same topic.
Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57746512/controller-method-persistence-issue

Comment: I have just added my proposed solution to your another question. 
BTW: If you fine with my solution for this question, could you mark my answer as "useful" or "answer" :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are not persisting account objects on which you update balance. Do you have entity mapping from transaction to individual account with cascade so that once transaction is saved corresponding accounts objects are also persisted.

Comment: I`ll update main code with two entity classes, take a look, please :)

Comment: `accountRepository.findById(result.getSenderAccountId()).get().setBalance(emitterFinalBalance);
accountRepository.findById(result.getReceiverAccountId()).get().setBalance(receptorFinalBalance);`

instead of above 2 lines, try

`result.getSenderAccountId().setBalance(emitterFinalBalance);
result.getReceiverAccountId().setBalance(receptorFinalBalance);`

Comment: Having this issue now:

Now it blames this line: Integer emitterBalance = accountRepository.findById(result.getSenderAccountId()).get().getBalance(); with Exception : "The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!"

Comment: Yeah, I have solved the main persistence question :) Thank you!