# Controller method persistence issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I have following scenario: two Entities - `Transaction` and `Account`
Transaction involves only two accounts.

After creation of transaction, amount of money from accountSender decrease while money for accountReceiver increase.

`Account` entity holds two lists - `transactionsMadeList` and `transactionsReceivedList` so overall it looks like that:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "holder": "Pavel S",
        "balance": -950,
        "transactionsMade": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "amount": 50,
                "created": "2019-09-01T13:37:24.565579Z",
                "senderAccountId": 1,
                "receiverAccountId": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "amount": 35,
                "created": "2019-09-01T13:37:24.614450Z",
                "senderAccountId": 1,
                "receiverAccountId": 2
            }
        ],
        "transactionsReceived": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "amount": 50,
                "created": "2019-09-01T13:37:24.609462Z",
                "senderAccountId": 2,
                "receiverAccountId": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "holder": "Gustaf S",
        "balance": 1070,
        "transactionsMade": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "amount": 50,
                "created": "2019-09-01T13:37:24.609462Z",
                "senderAccountId": 2,
                "receiverAccountId": 1
            }
        ],
        "transactionsReceived": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "amount": 50,
                "created": "2019-09-01T13:37:24.565579Z",
                "senderAccountId": 1,
                "receiverAccountId": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "amount": 35,
                "created": "2019-09-01T13:37:24.614450Z",
                "senderAccountId": 1,
                "receiverAccountId": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I implemented `Controller` method `[POST]` which creates a Transaction.
Code below:

```
@Transactional
    @PostMapping("/transactions")
    public ResponseEntity<Transaction> createTransaction(@Valid @RequestBody Transaction transaction) {
        final Transaction result = transactionRepository.save(transaction);
        final URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().
                path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(result.getId()).toUri();
        Account sender = accountRepository.findById(result.getSenderAccountId()).get();
        Account receiver = accountRepository.findById(result.getReceiverAccountId()).get();
        Transaction tr = transactionRepository.findById(result.getId()).get();
        Integer emitterBalance = accountRepository.findById(result.getSenderAccountId()).get().getBalance();
        Integer receptorBalance = accountRepository.findById(result.getReceiverAccountId()).get().getBalance();
        Integer amount = tr.getAmount();
        Integer emitterFinalBalance = emitterBalance - amount;
        Integer receptorFinalBalance = receptorBalance + amount;


        sender.setBalance(emitterFinalBalance);
        accountRepository.save(sender);

        receiver.setBalance(receptorFinalBalance);
        accountRepository.save(receiver);

        transactionRepository.save(result);
        transactionRepository.save(tr);
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
```

**My question is:** When I am persisting data to the database from a `CommandLineRunner` indirect static variables - transaction object is getting saved and then getting displayed in `transactionsMadeList/transactionsReceivedList` and also could be found by `[GET] ~/transactions` method
But when I am trying to create `Transaction` via `[POST] ~/transactions` method, `Transaction` is getting created but is not getting added to the `transactionsMade/transactionsReceived lists`

Would appreciate any help as I am kinda stack now with that :/
It seems that problem is in the persisting part in the Controller method
In case you will need Entity classes just tell me Ill post them as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the transactions into accounts.
(Removed mappedBy)
Try following:

Account class changes

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Transaction> transactionsMade = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Transaction> transactionsReceived = new ArrayList<>();
```

Controller:

```
@Transactional
@PostMapping("/transactions")
public ResponseEntity<Transaction> createTransaction(@Valid @RequestBody Transaction transaction) {
    final Transaction storedTransaction = transactionRepository.save(transaction);
    final URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().
            path("/{id}")
            .buildAndExpand(storedTransaction.getId()).toUri();
    Account sender = accountRepository.findById(storedTransaction.getSenderAccountId()).get();
    Account receiver = accountRepository.findById(storedTransaction.getReceiverAccountId()).get();
    Integer emitterBalance = accountRepository.findById(storedTransaction.getSenderAccountId()).get().getBalance();
    Integer receptorBalance = accountRepository.findById(storedTransaction.getReceiverAccountId()).get().getBalance();
    Integer amount = storedTransaction.getAmount();
    Integer emitterFinalBalance = emitterBalance - amount;
    Integer receptorFinalBalance = receptorBalance + amount;

    sender.setBalance(emitterFinalBalance);
    sender.getTransactionsMade().add(storedTransaction);
    accountRepository.save(sender);

    receiver.setBalance(receptorFinalBalance);
    receiver.getTransactionsReceived().add(storedTransaction);
    accountRepository.save(receiver);

    return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error message: Found shared references to a collection: com.monese.homework.model.entity.Account.transactionsReceived; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: com.monese.homework.model.entity.Account.transactionsReceived",

Comment: Could you try new version? :)
(we need to change Account)

Comment: same issue:
"Found shared references to a collection: com.monese.homework.model.entity.Account.transactionsReceived; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: com.monese.homework.model.entity.Account.transactionsReceived"

Comment: I have done refactoring (redundant save(...) calls have been removed ). Do not worry we will nail down the issue :) . This refactoring helps us to do this. Please try to run it.

Comment: It's now creating the transaction, but the transaction is still not getting added to the transactionsReceived/Made lists :(
Btw, we can move to the chat :)
P.S. Huge thanks for helping me to solve this issue :@

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198797/discussion-between-pavel-s-and-i-bondarenko).